# Upload and LAN issues in Nougat

Tags: backup, whatsapp-messenger, 7.0-nougat, lan

I recently switched phones to **Infinix Zero 4** running **Android N** and can't seem to get around the following issues:

1) My backup app (**Folder Sync Pro**) has not been able to complete a single backup since. The backup of small files (less than 200kb) completes while larger files fail with the error "`File transfer failed 'FULL_PATH_OF_FILE' - timeout`".

2) **Whatsapp** has not been able to complete it's nightly cloud backup. The best it has done is 61mb over a period of 10 hours.

3) I cannot access my computer via **ES File Explorer** over wifi. I've always been able to do this on previous phones.

My LAN is OK since I can upload files without issues via the computer. These symptoms suggest there is a problem with network handling either by the hardware, or Nougat.

Is there any hidden upload timeout setting on Android?
Is there any setting that would interfere with smb connection?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally figured out the root problem...

I have **Mobiwol NoRoot Firewall** installed and it seems to misbehave in Android N. Some apps get blocked unexpectedly so large uploads cannot complete. Disabling it allowed by backups to resume and complete as expected.